# ID is being cast to string, using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm having a problem trying to insert and object into a DB. Using var_dump it appears the ProductID is being cast to a string with value of 0.

var_dump shows:

```
object(Products)#1 (9) { ["ProductID"]=> string(1) "0" ["ProductTypeID"]=> int(1) ["Status"]=> int(1) ["Name"]=> string(1) "1" ["imgSrc"]=> string(1) "1" ["Price"]=> float(1) ["Veggie"]=> NULL ["Heated"]=> bool(true) ["Description"]=> string(1) "1" }
```

I beleive it should show:

```
object(Products)#1 (9) {  ["ProductID"]=> int(0) ["ProductTypeID"]=> int(1) ["Status"]=> int(1) ["Name"]=> string(1) "1" ["imgSrc"]=> string(1) "1" ["Price"]=> float(1) ["Veggie"]=> NULL ["Heated"]=> bool(true) ["Description"]=> string(1) "1" }
```

Would anyone mind taking a look to tell me whats going wrong?

```
<?php

function addBagel() {

  $results = array();
  $results['pageTitle'] = "New Bagel";
  $results['formAction'] = "addBagel";
  $results['formTitle'] = "Add a Product,";

  if ( isset( $_POST['saveChanges'] ) ) {

    // User has posted the object edit form: save the new product
    $product = new Products;
    $product->storeFormValues( $_POST );
    //Calls the inset function 
    $product->insert();

    var_dump($product);


    header( "Location: admin.php?&status=changesSaved" );

  } elseif ( isset( $_POST['cancel'] ) ) {

    // User has cancelled their edits: return to the product list
    header( "Location: admin.php?action=listArticles" );
  } else {

    // User has not posted the Product save form yet: display the form
    $results['product'] = new Products;

    $data = Products::getList();

    require( TEMPLATE_PATH . "/admin/editBagels.php" );
  }

}
?>

And my class;

<?php

class Products

{

  // Properties

  /**
  * @var int the id  
  */
  public $ProductID = null;

  /**
  * @var int product ID
  */
  public $ProductTypeID = null;

  /**
  * @var int the status of availability
  */
  public $Status = null;

  /**
  * @var string The name of the item
  */
  public $Name = null;

    /**
  * @var string src to associated image
  */
  public $imgSrc = null;

    /**
  * @var float src to associated image
  */
  public $Price = null;

    /**
  * @var string src to associated image
  */
  public $Veggie = null;

    /**
  * @var string src to associated image
  */
  public $Heated = null;

  /**
  * Sets the object's properties using the values in the supplied array
  *
  * @param assoc The property values
  */

  public function __construct( $data=array() ) {
    if ( isset( $data['ProductID'] ) ) $this->ProductID = (int) $data['ProductID'];
    if ( isset( $data['ProductTypeID'] ) ) $this->ProductTypeID = (int) $data['ProductTypeID']; 
    if ( isset( $data['Status'] ) ) $this->Status = (int) $data['Status'];
    if ( isset( $data['Name'] ) ) $this->Name = preg_replace ( "/[^\.\,\-\_\'\"\@\?\!\:\$ a-zA-Z0-9()]/", "", $data['Name'] );
    if ( isset( $data['Description'] ) ) $this->Description = preg_replace ( "/[^\.\,\-\_\'\"\@\?\!\:\$ a-zA-Z0-9()]/", "", $data['Description'] );
    if ( isset( $data['imgSrc'] ) ) $this->imgSrc = $data['imgSrc'];
    if ( isset( $data['Price'] ) ) $this->Price = (float) $data['Price'];
    if ( isset( $data['Veggie'] ) ) $this->Veggie = (bool) $data['Veggie'];
    if ( isset( $data['Heated'] ) ) $this->Heated = (bool) $data['Heated'];
  }

  /**
  * Sets the object's properties using the edit form post values in the supplied array
  *
  * @param assoc The form post values
  */

  public function storeFormValues ( $params ) {

    // Store all the parameters
    $this->__construct( $params );

  }


  /**
  * Inserts the current Product object into the database, and sets its ID property.
  */

  public function insert() {

    // Does the Product object already have an ID?
    if ( !is_null( $this->ProductID ) ) trigger_error ( "Product::insert(): Attempt to insert a Product object that already has its ID property set (to $this->ProductID).", E_USER_ERROR );

    $conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );

  // Insert the Article   
  $sql = "INSERT INTO Products ( ProductTypeID, Status, Name, Description, imgSrc, Price, Veggie, Heated) 
          VALUES (:ProductTypeID, :Status, :Name, :Description, :imgSrc, :Price, :Veggie, :Heated)";

    $st = $conn->prepare ( $sql );
     $st->bindValue( ":ProductTypeID", $this->ProductTypeID, PDO::PARAM_INT );
    $st->bindValue( ":Status", $this->Status, PDO::PARAM_INT );
    $st->bindValue( ":Name", $this->Name, PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $st->bindValue( ":Description", $this->Description, PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $st->bindValue( ":imgSrc", $this->imgSrc, PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $st->bindValue( ":Price", $this->Price, PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $st->bindValue( ":Veggie", $this->Veggie, PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $st->bindValue( ":Heated", $this->Heated, PDO::PARAM_STR );

    $st->execute();

    $this->ProductID = $conn->lastInsertId();
    print_r( $this );

    $conn = null;

  }

?>
```

### -- Table structure for table `Products`

```
CREATE TABLE `Products` (
`ProductID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ProductTypeID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `Description` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `imgSrc` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `Price` float NOT NULL,
  `Veggie` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `Heated` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`PDO::lastInsertId()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php) returns a string. It's because some databases do not necessarily have to use integers, sequences in postgres can be also strings. Cast it using `(int)$conn->lastInsertId();` if it matters. I hope you set `PDO` to throw exceptions on errors.

Comment: Thanks Marek, thats great, working perfectly. Found another error in my form/input the value for Veggie was set to vegaterian, hence returning NULL in the dump. All working great now. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Set attribute for `$conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD )` like below could work too. The int type would not convert to string.

`$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES , false);`

> `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` Enables or disables emulation of prepared statements. Some drivers do not support native prepared statements or have limited support for them. Use this setting to force PDO to either always emulate prepared statements (if TRUE and emulated prepares are supported by the driver), or to try to use native prepared statements (if FALSE). It will always fall back to emulating the prepared statement if the driver cannot successfully prepare the current query. Requires bool.

The `emulate prepared statements` will auto convert int to string. The reason maybe as the accepted answerer said `It's because some databases do not necessarily have to use integers, sequences in postgres can be also strings.`